# Cannot execute two changelogs for two databases from Liquibase maven plugin

Tags: maven, liquibase

I currently have two different databases:Oracle and DB2. I am trying to use the maven plugin for liquibase to run two different changelogs on these two databases.

What I have so far:

In my configuration, i set up both Oracle and DB2 connection:

```
<configuration>
     <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/liquibase/changelogORACLE.xml</changeLogFile>
     <driver>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver>
     <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@vdfdfseisfs3:3131:orcl</url>
     <username>liquibase</username>
     <password>password</password>

     <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/liquibase/changelogDB2.xml</changeLogFile>
     <driver>com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</driver>
     <url>jdbc:db2://111.111.1.11:10000/test</url>
     <username>Admini</username>
     <password>password</password>
</configuration>
```

And in my execution I have set up like this:

```
<execution>
    <phase>process-resources</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>update</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```

And I have both dependency set up:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <artifactId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</artifactId>
    <groupId>db2jcc</groupId>
    <version>4.9.78</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/my-repo/com/ibm/db2/jcc/db2jcc/4.9.78/db2jcc-4.9.78.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

My question is, when I run from the windows `CMD` like this: `mvn liquibase:update`

Only the DB2 changelog will be executed, so I will have data created for the DB2 database, but not Oracle. Why only one changelog file gets executed?

I can individually execute Oracle and DB2 changelogs, but I want to execute both of them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Liquibase maven plugin most likely does not allow for two configurations in this section of your pom:

```
<configuration>
     <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/liquibase/changelogORACLE.xml</changeLogFile>
     <driver>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver>
     <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@vdfdfseisfs3:3131:orcl</url>
     <username>liquibase</username>
     <password>password</password>

     <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/liquibase/changelogDB2.xml</changeLogFile>
     <driver>com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</driver>
     <url>jdbc:db2://111.111.1.11:10000/test</url>
     <username>Admini</username>
     <password>password</password>
</configuration>
```

It is probably only reading the first one. From reading the Maven lifecycle docs, it appears you can do what you want by using two different executions, but I am not clear how you would alter the pom to have the two executions use two different configurations.

Comment: i solved the problem by doing this: http://freekode.org/liquibase-multiple-db/  Problem is it will build success only if I do `mvn install`, it will not work if I do `mvn liquibase:update`

Comment: Maybe you can use maven profiles and execute it twice?